# Laravel Eloquent Relationship custom query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, entity-relationship

I have 2 tables: `USERS` and `SUBJECTS`

The relationship between `USER` and `SUBJECT` is many to many.
In the User.php and Subject.php models, I defined:

User.php

```
function subjects() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\User'); }
```

Subject.php

```
function users() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject'); }
```

The pivot table is `subject_user` and it has 3 columns:
`subject_id`, `user_id`, `finished`

The `finished` value can only be between 0 and 1.

Now I know that when I want to select all the subjects that an user studied, I have to write `$user->subjects`.

But what if I want to select all the subjects that an user studied and the finished value in the pivot table is equal to 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add "withPivot()" to your relationship definitions, like this:

```
function subjects() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('finished'); }

function users() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject')->withPivot('finished'); }
```

Then you can do:

```
$user->subjects()->where('finished', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to eager load that relationship and use the `wherePivot` method.

```
$user = User::with(['subjects' => function($q) {
    $q->wherePivot('finished', 1);
}])->fine($user_id);
```